# Проверка переменной оператором javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    var active=0;
    var online=1;
    if([online == 1][active === 0])
    {
    active=1;
    alert('принято')
    } 
    else {
    active=0;alert('отказ');
    }
```

Условия соблюдены, но срабатывает else. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Квадратными скобками обозначается [литерал массива](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Таким образом внутри `if` происходит следующее:

1. создается массив с одним элементом: `[online == 1]`, так как `online` действительно равен `1` - результат сравнения `true`, поэтому эту часть можно заменить на `[true]`.
2. идет попытка получения у указанного выше массива свойства, имя свойства определяется так: `active === 0`, результат `true`. При использовании [скобочной нотации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) имя свойства переводится в строку. Таким образом у массива получается свойство с именем `true`. Так как такого свойства у массива нет, результат - *undefined*.
3. *undefined* - в условиях эквивалентно `false`, поэтому выполняется ветка `else.

---

для избегания подобных ошибок не нужно использовать литерал массива, а для объединения проверок необходимо использовать [логические операторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

```js
var active = 0;
var online = 1;
if (online == 1 && active === 0) {
  active = 1;
  console.log('принято')
} else {
  active = 0;
  console.log('отказ');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно у вас ошибка в **if**. Перепишите вот так:

```
var active=0;
var online=1;
if(online === 1 && active === 0)
{
active=1;
alert('принято')
} 
else {
active=0;alert('отказ');
}
```